# Кастомный ListView во фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Здравствуйте.

Мне нужно в один из фрагментов "засунуть" кастомный ListView.

*Fragment1.java*

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.four, null);

    final ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        }

        public void onCreate (Bundle icicle) {

            // Адаптер
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Name", "1. Русский язык");
            map.put("Tel", "4");

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(),
                    myArrList,
                    R.layout.row,
                    new String[]{"Name", "Tel"},
                    new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2});
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
}
```

На эмуляторе приложение запускается, но потом аварийно завершается.

Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Посмотрите в логе, в какой строке вываливается ошибка?

Comment: Стектрейс добавьте. Думаете здесь телепатов полно, угадывать какая там у вас ошибка

Comment: Откуда в ```OnClickListener``` появился метод ```onCreate```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дошёл до всего сам. Отвечаю на свой же вопрос, вдруг кому-нибудь понадобится:

Мой *Fragment2.java:*

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.five, null);

    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    });

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Name", "Алгебра");
    map.put("Tel", "4.45");
    myArrList.add(map);

    map=new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Name","Английский язык");
    map.put("Tel","4.55");
    myArrList.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            myArrList,
            R.layout.row,
            new String[]{"Name", "Tel"},
            new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
}
```

Разметка на *row.xml:*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/RelLay"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tel"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```